# Where does lightning mostly strike in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My problem is that when I go to a mountain and switch the weather to thunder, I never really get any lightning.

Answer (score 6):

Other than needing a biome where it rains (not snows), lighting strikes are completely random. Every tick there is a 1 in 100 thousand chance that lightning will strike in a particular chunk. If this check passes, it picks a random x, z, and selects the highest block on that coordinate. If that block can see the sky, and rain is falling on it, lightning strikes. There is no way to increase the chance of lightning strike. ([Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Thunderstorm))

Comment: The rain requirement might be why you aren't getting any nearby strikes, though. There is no thundersnow in Minecraft.

Comment: although your chance part is right, but there is such a thing as thunder there are 3 types of weather in minecraft Clear, Rain and Thunder if the weather is not thunder then there is 0% chance of lightning during thunder storms the sky is darker than when it rains and there is a chance of thunder.